# transfer soap API data "suds.sax.text.Text" in html/xml to json

Tags: python, html, json, xml, suds

I am getting some data from a soap API which returns data in html/xml format , with lots of content format info in it : like "`</span></span></span>\`"  "`</code></pre>`"

I know normally developer can use some API which fetch json data directly from website, but this soap API which returns html/xml data is the only API I have. 
So how can I remove all "format" info and leave the real content only ?  Ideally I want to transfer it from html/xml to json , any python3 package I can use and how ?